# Randomly initiated vectors with norm equals to one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-algebra

I want to randomly initiate a non-negative vector `R`, such that `||R|| = 1`? Here `R` is a ranking vector. I have used the following code. Is it correct?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA

R = np.random.rand(1,25)
norm_R = LA.norm(R, 2)
Rv = np.true_divide(R, norm_R)
norm_Rv = LA.norm(Rv, 2)
print (norm_Rv)
```

Comment: What is a "non-negative" vector ? Each component is positive ? Do you want to randomly generate it in a *uniform* way ?

Comment: I am trying to implement an algorithm (Page 4, point #3) given in a paper "A Three-Layered Mutually Reinforced Model for Personalized Citation Recommendation". No other details are given in this paper. The only information is that "randomly initiated non-negative vector, such that ||R|| = 1. I guess all elements of the vector are non-negative.